# documentation about configuration tag in maven-ear-plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, configuration, ear

I cannot find any documentation related to plugins -> plugin -> configuration -> version for maven-ear-plugin:

```
<plugins>      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.ear.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
            <version>7</version>
```

I think that is somewhat related to te EE version, but can anyone point to the documentation and some examples?

Comment: What about: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form plugin documentation:

> The version of the application.xml to generate.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#version

Supplement for documentation, current allowed values are:

- 1.3 - J2EE 1.3 version.
- 1.4 - J2EE 1.4 version.
- 5 -  JavaEE 5 version.
- 6 - JavaEE 6 version.
- 7 - JavaEE 7 version.
- 8 - JavaEE 8 version.
- 9 - JakartaEE 9 version.
- 10 - JakartaEE 10 version.

So it is version of generated `application.xml` descriptor.

More information about application descriptor:
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html
https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/